# Why is there no "s" in "look" in the following phrase: A meta viewport tag makes the page look good on all screen sizes

Tags: word-usage, verbs, nouns

Since "page" is a third-person singular noun, "look" should be "looks", right?? Is that phrase correct or just misspelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is correct. After 'makes' or 'make', also 'let', a verb must be in its base (infinitive without 'to') form.

> A meta viewport tag makes the page **look** good on all screen sizes.
>
> A thick coat makes me **feel** warm in winter.
>
> Sunlight and water make plants **grow**.
>
> The cruel man beat his dog to make it **howl**.

> *Verbs followed by an infinitive without to
>
> Let, make*
> *Let and make are followed by an infinitive without to in active voice sentences. They always have an object before the infinitive:*
>
> *Let me show you this DVD I’ve got.*
> *They made us wait while they checked our documents.*

[Verb patterns with infinitive (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing)

Comment: +1 And to add that only one verb can conjugate to take the tense. "Makes" is already conjugated and has present simple for third person singular, and it is not part of a compound verb with "look" (like "*makes and looks*"), so no other verb will have tense in that clause. Michael points out the correct rule for determining the form of "look".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there really is no such thing as a first person or third-person noun. Any noun can be used in a first-person or third person construction. For example:

> - I am David.
> - David is the person with the grey hair over there.
> - I am reading page four.
> - David designed this page.

That being said, let's consider some examples and reasons:

> - The page looks good. [image: Green check, indicating a valid form]

```
The verb *looks* is in its singular form.
```

> - The red stripe makes the page look good.  [image: Green check, indicating a valid form]

The verb *makes* is in its singular form. After the use of "makes" the verb "look" must be in its base form. For regular verbs, the base form is the same as the third-person plural form.

> - The red stripe makes the page looks good. [image: Red X, indicating an invalid form]

After the use of "makes" a plural form is not grammatical.